# redux-actions handleActions isn't changing the state

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I have a bunch of ducks style redux modules that look like this:

```
import { createAction, handleActions } from 'redux-actions'

const SET = "error/SET"
const CLEAR = "error/CLEAR"

export default handleActions({
  SET: (error, action) => action.payload,
  CLEAR: (error, action) => ""
}, "")

export const setError = createAction(SET)
export const clearError = createAction(CLEAR)
```

then, in reducers.js I do this:

```
import error from './error'

export default combineReducers({
  error,
  ...
})
```

yet, when I dispatch(setError("ERROR")) I see the action in redux devtools, but the state does not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing map with wrong keys to `handleActions`. You don't want keys to be `SET` and `CLEAR`, but their values instead (`error/SET` and `error/CLEAR`). To do so you have to wrap them in square brackets:

```
export default handleActions({
  [SET]: (error, action) => action.payload,
  [CLEAR]: (error, action) => ""
}, "")
```